# Create Random number sequence without duplicates in excel for almost million rows or records

Tags: excel, function, random, numbers, sequence

I would want to create a random sequence of numbers in 11 digit format and that should run from 10000000000 to 999999999999 and each of the values should be unique and i would like to populate almost 20-50 million worth of records in excel without having to keep dragging all the way down at the bottom of the cell by clicking + button

I tried using  RANDBETWEEN but seems like there are duplicates and i have to keep dragging which is a time consuming activity,is there any alternative better way to accomplish this ?

```
=RANDBETWEEN(10000000000,999999999999)
```

Comment: You're using the wrong tool for this. Excel tops out at just over 1 million records. And it's horrible with that much data.

Comment: Any other option on what tool i could try and copy it over into excel

Comment: What is your *actual* end goal? What do you need these numbers for?

Comment: I am creating a test data random number sequence worth multi million records and would prefer the digits starting at the 10000000000 and sprawling all the way to max range of 999999999999 and to run a test sequence in an external tool for validation purpose

Comment: Try Python and numpy.

Answer (score 0):

For that many unique numbers I suggest using an encryption, where the output is guaranteed unique for unique inputs.

Simply encrypt the numbers 0, 1, 2, ... for different unique inputs.  You will need to use the same encryption key and other inputs (IV, nonce etc.) to guarantee unique outputs.

You will need to do some processing on the outputs to get them into the required range.  Have a look at [Format Preserving Encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format-preserving_encryption) for some help with this.

As @BigBen pointed out, Excel is probably the wrong tool for this.